# Incorrect upload multiple images in Edit method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have method Edit that uploads one image for Main Page and  multiple images for gallery  to the existing record in database. I have one to many relationship table (`FurnitureImages` where I store info about image) , also  I use View Model
So here my code

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(FurnitureVM model)
{
    if (model.MainFile != null && model.MainFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string displayName = model.MainFile.FileName;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(displayName);
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), extension);
        string path = "~/Upload/" + fileName;
        model.MainFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath( path));
        model.MainImage = new ImageVM() { Path = path, DisplayName = displayName };
    }     
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in model.SecondaryFiles)
    {
        FurnitureImages images = new FurnitureImages();
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string displayName = file.FileName;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(displayName);
            string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), extension);
            var path = "~/Upload/" + fileName;
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
            model.SecondaryImages = new List<ImageVM> { new ImageVM { DisplayName = displayName, Path = path } };
        }
    }
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.CategoryList = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name",model.CategoryId); // repopulate the SelectList
        return View(model);
    }

    Furniture furniture = db.Furnitures.Where(x => x.FurnitureId == model.ID).FirstOrDefault();
    FurnitureImages main = furniture.Images.Where(x => x.IsMainImage).FirstOrDefault();
    furniture.Name = model.Name;
    furniture.Description = model.Description;
    furniture.Manufacturer = model.Manufacturer;
    furniture.Price = model.Price;
    furniture.CategoryId = model.CategoryId;
    furniture.Size = model.Size;       
    main.DisplayName = model.MainImage.DisplayName;
    main.Path = model.MainImage.Path;
    main.IsMainImage = model.MainImage.IsMainImage;
    if (model.MainImage != null && !model.MainImage.Id.HasValue)
    {
        FurnitureImages image = new FurnitureImages
        {
            Path = model.MainImage.Path,
            DisplayName = model.MainImage.DisplayName,
            IsMainImage = true
        };
        furniture.Images.Add(image);
        db.Entry(furniture).State = EntityState.Modified;
    } 
    // Update secondary images
    IEnumerable<ImageVM> newImages = model.SecondaryImages.Where(x => x.Id == null);
    foreach (ImageVM image in newImages)
    {
        FurnitureImages images = new FurnitureImages
        {
            DisplayName = image.DisplayName,
            Path =  image.Path , 
            IsMainImage = false
        };
        furniture.Images.Add(images);
    }
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name", furniture.CategoryId);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Main image uploads good , but when I try to upload multiple images from another input file

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecondaryFiles, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" , name = "SecondaryFiles" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SecondaryFiles)
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SecondaryImages.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].Path)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].DisplayName)
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.SecondaryImages[i].Path)" />
}
```

It uploads only one image , And as much as I keep trying to upload many images, it always upload only one, so where are errors in my method?

Comment: Call `db.Entry(furniture).State = EntityState.Modified;` immediately before `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i tried it , something wrong  , uploads only 1 image , when I select 2 or more

Comment: Do you mean it uploads only one of the `SecondaryImages` when you select more that one? (and are you referring to uploading (saving the file to disk) or saving the item to the database in the `FurnitureImages` table?)

Comment: You have a few other issues with your code - but what your referring to is caused by your `model.SecondaryImages = new List<ImageVM> { new ImageVM { DisplayName = displayName, Path = path } };` - you keep overwriting the collection. It needs to be `model.SecondaryImages.Add(new ImageVM { ... })` inside the loop

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes , I mean it uploads only one of the SecondaryImages when I select more that one . In my logic when I upload image it uploads to the folder in file system and info about image creates and store in database , I tried to add EntityState.Added but I get an error

Comment: Did you not read my last comment?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry , I saw your comment when I wrote new one , now it works , thank you

Comment: There are a couple of other issues you should address and I'll add an answer later

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay , thanks

Comment: can any 1 give answer of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439592/modelstate-isvalid-returns-false-only-when-resource-language-changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that inside the first `foreach` loop, you correctly save each file to the server, but in each iteration, your creating an new `List<ImageVM>` and overwriting the value of `SecondaryImages` so when the loop has completed, it contains only one item (based on the last image).

Change the loop to

```
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in model.SecondaryFiles)
{
    // FurnitureImages images = new FurnitureImages(); -- DELETE
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string displayName = file.FileName;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(displayName);
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), extension);
        var path = "~/Upload/" + fileName;
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
        // Add a new ImageVM to the collection 
        model.SecondaryImages.Add(new ImageVM { DisplayName = displayName, Path = path });
    }
}
```

Note that the above assumes you view model has a parameter-less constructor that initializes `SecondaryImages`. If not, then add `model.SecondaryImages = new List<ImageVM>` before the loop.

A few other minor issues to address.

1. The code for generating the `SelectList` should be just
   `model.CategoryList = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name");` - the last parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is
   ignored when binding to a model property so its pointless.
2. Delete the `ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(...)` line of code.
   Your model already contains a property for the `SelectList` (as per
   note 1) but in any case, your redirecting, so adding anything to
   `ViewBag` is pointless.
3. Move your `db.Entry(furniture).State = EntityState.Modified;` line
   of code to immediately before `db.SaveChanges();`